# Nvidia Graphics Card and 4 monitors

Tags: 10.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

Hi I am using a Nvidia Quadro NVs 420 on a HP desktop. When I put the card in I can see the BIOS screen but I do not see anything after that. If I put the card in my Windows XP computer I get all 4 monitors working. How can I get this graphics card to work with my Ubuntu computer. I am using Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS btw

Answer (score 1):

I've not configured 4 displays with a single card but some of the things you will need to have would be:

1. Native nvidia driver.  Preferably the latest which is 290.10
2. You will need to enable TwinView and you can see the options here: http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/290.10/README/index.html

Normally for Twinview you would set up `Metamode` for 2 displays, but general I don't see any reason why you wouldn't be able to do the same for 4.

Once Twinview is set up if you are running 2 pair of displays you would also need to enable Xinerama in /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Option Xinerama "on"
```